# Cannot send message without a sender address in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

In my **Laravel 5.4** app I want to send an email notification to the user when they *signup* I have set everything but not work and shown an exception like:

```
Cannot send message without a sender address
```

I am using **mailtrap**.

I have also run the artisan command `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan cache:clear`

**This is my .env file**:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=3e917ca6b3dabc
MAIL_PASSWORD=05abe282eca67f
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the exact same problem with Laravel 6.15.1.

As it turned out, you only need to delete these lines in `.env`:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please update your `.env` file like:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=youremailaddress
MAIL_PASSWORD=gtxajikwsqmlaqc //your app password
```

Comment: I want to use mailtrap not gmail

Comment: @ShahidHussain: Difference is `MAIL_USERNAME`  && `MAIL_PASSWORD`

Comment: MAIL_USERNAME && MAIL_PASSWORD is already using so which MAIL_USERNAME && MAIL_PASSWORD are you talking about

Comment: @ShahidHussain: Please check this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/ultimate-guide-on-sending-email-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2):

In your `.env` file you will need to set the email address and password of your email account.

---

Steps to configure mailtrap:

1) Register to mailtrap: https://mailtrap.io/register/signup

2) Go to Inbox page: https://mailtrap.io/inboxes

3) Click on Demo Inbox link and you will see the following mailtrap smtp credentials, Where the username and password will be something like this:

```
"username" => "b8f19cb615a7b3",
"password" => "8218011886905f",
```

Now change to *`.env`* file in the root directory of your project and change the following line:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=***USER NAME***
MAIL_PASSWORD=***PASSWORD***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

After completion of *`.env`* edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: mailtrap is working in laravel 5.6 but not in laravel 5.4 so what is the reasion

Comment: i do not want use gmail i want to use mailtrap

Comment: @ShahidHussain this is the correct answer, check your `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null` instead of tls for diagnosing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't restart your service. You should restart your service by 2 steps:

Step 1: Stop your service (CMD):

```
Ctrl + C
```

Step 2: You run service again:

```
npm run dev
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your environment variables in your `.env` file.

They should look something like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Secondly check that you have a mail from address, as your error suggests you cannot send an email without a send address.

**config/mail.php**

Check for

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

You can set `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` and `MAIL_FROM_NAME` in your `.env` file e.g.

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Example"
```

**If you're using a mailable**

You can set who the email is from in your `build()` function e.g.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#generating-mailables)

```
/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
                ->view('emails.orders.shipped');
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code that is sending the email?